# nested list equal value append

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list like this.

```
 [['a','g','c'],['e','c','g']...]
```

I am trying to see if third entry is equal to second entry in the list. If it is, I want to return first entry in that list. So since 3rd entry in list 1 is c, I want to look for c in second entry in all the list. Since list 2 has corresponding value in 2nd entry, I want to return e, then append that to nested list 1. There are multiple lists,and want to do it for all the list.

So

```
 [['a','g','c','e']...]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below,

```
>>> l = [['a','g','c'],['e','c','g']]
>>> i = l[0][2]                      # stores the value of 2nd index of l[0] to the variable i
>>> m = l[0]                         # assigns the 0th index of l to m
>>> for j in l[1:]:
        if i == j[1]:
            m.append(j[0])


>>> m
['a', 'g', 'c', 'e']
```

A complex example.

```
>>> l = [['a','g','c'],['e','c','g'], ['m','c','g'], ['j','c','g'], ['k','f','g'], ['p','c','g']]
>>> i = l[0][2]
>>> m = l[0]
>>> for j in l[1:]:
        if i == j[1]:
            m.append(j[0])

>>> m
['a', 'g', 'c', 'e', 'm', 'j', 'p']
```

Comment: What about for multiple lists, not just two?

Comment: I want to append to the corresponding list, not just in one list. So [a,g,c,e], [e,c,g,j]...etc

Comment: Does this clarify? Thx for input.

Answer (score 0):

```
k=[['a','g','c'],['e','c','g'],['m','c','g'],['j','c','g'],['k','f','g'],['p','g','k']]


print [x+y[:1] for x,y in zip(k,k[1:]) if x[2]==y[1]]
```

Try this.